# autoHeight property is not working in ag-grid-angular after upgrading to Angular14

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using Angular Grid in my project. I want to increase the row height dynamically based on the largest content of cell. I have tried with autoHeight: true, wrapText: true, & cellClass: 'cell-wrap-text'(for white-space: normal style). These configurations are working perfectly in Angular13, recently upgraded to angular 14 later onwards auto row height is not working. Any help is appreciated.

component.html:

```
      <ag-grid-angular
                 #grid
                  *ngIf="data"
                 [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
                 [rowData]="data"                     
                 [columnDefs]="ColDef">
      </ag-grid-angular>
```

component.ts:

```
      export class GridComponent implements OnInit {
              @Input() data!: GridData[];
              resizeObserver!: ResizeObserver;
             ColDef = [
                       {
                        headerName: 'Details', field: 'details',            
                        autoHeight: true,wrapText: true, cellClass: 'cell-wrap-text',                                      
                       },
                       {
                        headerName: 'Message', field: 'message',          
                        autoHeight: true,,wrapText: true, cellClass: 'cell-wrap-text',                   
                       },
];

constructor(private hostElementRef: ElementRef) {
}

ngOnInit() {
           this.resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => {
                this.grid.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
                this.grid.api.resetRowHeights();
           });
        this.resizeObserver.observe(this.hostElementRef.nativeElement);
}
```

}

component.scss:

```
         ::ng-deep .cell-wrap-text {
           white-space: normal !important;
          }
```

After upgrading ng14 autoHeight is not working. I have tried with ResizeObserver also like when grid resize, I have called this.grid.api.resetRowHeights() & this.grid.api.sizeColumnsToFit() but no use.

[image]

Note: AG Grid: tried to call sizeColumnsToFit() but the grid is coming back with zero width, maybe the grid is not visible yet on the screen?

Above warning message is also coming.